# Ensure thread safety in the code

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm trying to write a multi-threaded code to achieve parallelism for a task that is taking too much time. Here is how it looks:

```
class A
  attr_reader :mutex, :logger
  def initialize
    @reciever = ZeroMQ::Queue
    @sender = ZeroMQ::Queue
    @mutex = Mutex.new
    @logger = Logger.new('log/test.log')
  end

  def run
    50.times do 
      Thread.new do 
        run_parallel(@reciever.get_data)
      end
    end
  end

  def run_parallel(data)  
    ## Define some local variables.
    a , b = data
    ## Log some data to file.
    logger.info "Got #{a}"
    output =  B.get_data(b)
    ## Send output back to zermoq.
    mutex.synchronize { @sender.send_data(output} }
  end
end
```

One needs to make sure that code is thread safe. Sharing and changing data (like `@`,`@@`,`$` without proper mutex) across threads could lead to thread safety issue.

I'm not sure whether if I pass the data to a method, that results in thread safety issue as well. In other words, do I have to ensure that the part of my code inside `run_parallel` has to be wrapped in a `mutex` if I'm not using any `@`, `@@`, `$` inside the method? Or is the given mutex definition enough?

```
mutex.synchronize { @sender.send_data(output} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you're running in a threaded context, you've got to be aware (for a simple heuristic) of anything that's not a local variable. I see these potential problems in your code:

- `run_parallel(@reciever.get_data)` Is `get_data` threadsafe? You've synchronized `send_data`, and they're both a `ZeroMQ::Queue`, so I'm guessing not.
- `output =  B.get_data(b)` Is this call threadsafe? If it just pulls something out of `b`, you're fine, but if it uses state in `B` or calls anything else that has state, you're in trouble.
- `logger.info "Got #{a}"` [@coreyward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203130/coreyward) points out that `Logger` is threadsafe, so this is no trouble. Just make sure to stick with it over `puts`, which will garble your output.

Once you're inside the mutex for `@sender.send_data`, you're safe, assuming `@sender` isn't accessed anywhere else in your code by another thread. Of course, the more `synchronize` you throw around, the more your threads will block on each other and lose performance, so there's a balance you need to find your design.

Do what you can to make your code functional: try to use only local state and write methods that don't have side effects. As your task gets more complicated, there are libraries like [concurrent-ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) with threadsafe data structures and other patterns that can help.

Comment: For what it's worth, `Logger` is threadsafe, so output should be as expected.

Comment: Excellent, thanks @coreyward. If anyone wants a quick empirical test, `Array.new(500) {|i| Thread.new { 1000.times {|j| Rails.logger.info "#{i}-#{j}"}}}.each(&:join)`.